# Obtaining SwiftUI view size (height/width) with GeometryReader not returning correct values

Tags: swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I have the following code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 50)
                
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        VStack {
                            circleButton()
                            circleButton()
                            circleButton()
                        }
                        .background(.orange)
                        .coordinateSpace(name: "3Buttons")
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        let _ = print("GLOBAL: x: \(geo.frame(in: .global).origin.x), y: \(geo.frame(in: .global).origin.y), width: \(geo.frame(in: .global).width), height: \(geo.frame(in: .global).size.height)\n")
                        let _ = print("LOCAL: x: \(geo.frame(in: .local).origin.x), y: \(geo.frame(in: .local).origin.y), width: \(geo.frame(in: .local).width), height: \(geo.frame(in: .local).size.height)\n")
                        let _ = print("3Buttons: x: \(geo.frame(in: .named("3Buttons")).origin.x), y: \(geo.frame(in: .named("3Buttons")).origin.y), width: \(geo.frame(in: .named("3Buttons")).width), height: \(geo.frame(in: .named("3Buttons")).height)\n")
                        let _ = print("2Buttons: x: \(geo.frame(in: .named("2Buttons")).origin.x), y: \(geo.frame(in: .named("2Buttons")).origin.y), width: \(geo.frame(in: .named("2Buttons")).width), height: \(geo.frame(in: .named("2Buttons")).height)\n")
                        
                        VStack {
                            circleButton()
                            circleButton()
                        }
                        .background(.red)
                        .coordinateSpace(name: "2Buttons")
                    }
                }
            }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    func circleButton() -> some View {
        Button {
            print()
        } label: {
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Which is producing the following outcome:

[image: Image showing 3 circle buttons left, 50 points inset from the top, with total approximate height of 150ish on an orange background]

I'm trying to obtain both origin x & y relative to its parent [i.e. the red background view should likely have origin of say (600, 0) with size (40, 100)], as well as the view/backgrounds size [say (40, 100)].

Printing out the various named coordinateSpaces, .global, and .local... all return the same height, width, etc. The resulting printouts are as follows:

```
GLOBAL: x: 0.0, y: 109.0, width: 393.0, height: 701.0

LOCAL: x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 393.0, height: 701.0

3Buttons: x: 0.0, y: 109.0, width: 393.0, height: 701.0

2Buttons: x: 0.0, y: 109.0, width: 393.0, height: 701.0
```

It doesn't seem to matter where I place the geometry reader or the printouts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I possibly have answered my own question. As I understand it now, GeometryReader expands to fill the space where it's used.

Using it in either

a) .background and returning .clear color, or

b) .overlay [Although I've not tried this]

will return the appropriate size.

Sample code:

A:

```
Button {
    print()
} label: {
    Text("Button")
}
.background {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Color.clear
        let _ = print("Button size: \(geo.size)")
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Button size: (68.0, 20.333333333333332)
```

I suspect there is a better way though, so this should not be the accepted answer. This seems like a workaround that was likely necessary at some point, but has likely been replaced by a more appropriate solution or will be soon... one would think.

Comment: Using a `background` or `overlay` like you are doing with `GeometryReader` is a pretty common solution to this issue.

Comment: Whether there is a better way depends on why you want the size.

Comment: @robmayoff the reason for the size in this case is as follows: I have an app where the user can draw, and there are various buttons on the screen (color selection, tool selection) etc like the buttons pictured in the example above. You provide to a separate struct a "protected area" (in this case the buttons), a buffer (say 50pts), and a touch point. The struct returns you the % the touch point is in the buffer zone (1.0 would be fully in the protected area, 0 not in the buffer, 0.1 10% in). This in turn is used as an opacity to hide the buttons as the touch point nears the protected area.